# Error 404 when changing tab

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I get this error when I change tb to New Project tab and Settings Tab, why? Can't find what does that. It only happens once per tab.

Im on google chrome btw. Never had this problem before and well i havent done anything special in this app.

Here is my tab code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.GeneralTabs', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.SingleConstant',
    'MyApp.view.ConstantsSpacer',
    'MyApp.view.MultipleConstants'
],

config: {
    id: 'generaltabs',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Projects',
            iconCls: 'list',
            id: 'projectstab'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'New Project',
            iconCls: 'add',
            id: 'createtab',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1,
                    id: 'createnamefield',
                    label: 'Name',
                    placeHolder: 'CarboZero'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    flex: 1,
                    id: 'createselector',
                    label: 'Type',
                    options: [
                        {
                            text: 'Event',
                            value: 'Event'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Trip',
                            value: 'Trip'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Business',
                            value: 'Business'
                        }
                    ],
                    usePicker: false
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer',
                    flex: 5,
                    id: 'createspacer',
                    width: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    id: 'createsavecontainer',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer',
                            flex: 1,
                            id: 'createsavespacer'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            flex: 1,
                            id: 'createbutton',
                            icon: 'true',
                            iconCls: 'action',
                            text: 'Create'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer',
                            flex: 1,
                            id: 'createsavespacer2'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'About',
            iconCls: 'info',
            id: 'abouttab',
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'carousel',
                    id: 'aboutcarousel',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            html: '<center>Awareness Tab</center>',
                            id: 'aboutawareness'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            html: '<center>Goal tab</center>',
                            id: 'aboutgoal'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            html: '<center>Sources and Partners</center>',
                            id: 'aboutsources'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Settings',
            iconCls: 'settings',
            id: 'settingstab',
            layout: {
                type: 'card'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    id: 'SettingsGeneralSettings',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            flex: 3,
                            id: 'SettingLanguage',
                            label: 'Language',
                            placeHolder: 'English',
                            options: [
                                {
                                    text: 'English',
                                    value: 'English'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Français',
                                    value: 'Français'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Espanol',
                                    value: 'Espanol'
                                }
                            ],
                            usePicker: false
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer',
                            flex: 1,
                            id: 'SettingsSpacer1',
                            width: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            flex: 3,
                            id: 'SettingsUnits',
                            label: 'Units',
                            placeHolder: 'International',
                            options: [
                                {
                                    text: 'American',
                                    value: 'American'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Imperial',
                                    value: 'Imperial'
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'International',
                                    value: 'International'
                                }
                            ],
                            usePicker: false
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer',
                            flex: 5,
                            id: 'SettingsSpacer2',
                            width: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            flex: 3,
                            id: 'settingsconstantsbutton',
                            ui: 'plain',
                            icon: 'true',
                            iconAlign: 'right',
                            iconCls: 'action',
                            text: 'Constants'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    id: 'settingsconstantscard',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'singleconstant',
                            id: 'singleconstant',
                            label: 'FirePit',
                            labelWidth: '60%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'constantsspacer',
                            id: 'constantsspacer',
                            maxHeight: 5,
                            minHeight: 0
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'multipleconstants',
                            id: 'Constantsmultipleconstants'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            id: 'generaltitle',
            title: 'CarboZero',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    hidden: true,
                    id: 'settingsbackbutton',
                    itemId: 'backbutton1',
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Settings'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'bottom',
        id: 'generaltabsconfig'
    },
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybutton1Tap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#settingsconstantsbutton'
        },
        {
            fn: 'onSettingsbackbuttonTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#settingsbackbutton'
        },
        {
            fn: 'onGeneraltabsActiveItemChange',
            event: 'activeitemchange'
        }
    ]
},

onMybutton1Tap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    button.getParent().getParent().getParent().getAt(5).getAt(0).getAt(0).show();
    button.getParent().getParent().setActiveItem(1);
},

onSettingsbackbuttonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    button.hide();
    button.getParent().getParent().getParent().getAt(4).setActiveItem(0);
},

onGeneraltabsActiveItemChange: function(container, value, oldValue, eOpts) {

    container.getAt(5).getAt(0).getAt(0).hide();        
}

});
```

Here is the error

```
GET http://localhost/~guillaumecharron/CarboZero/true 404 (Not Found) sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.dom.Element.override.getPageBox sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.getContainerBox sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.getElementBox sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.getData sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.run sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onActiveItemChange sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.relayEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onContainerActiveItemChange sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fireAction sencha-touch-all.js:21
(anonymous function) sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doTabChange sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fireAction sencha-touch-all.js:21
(anonymous function) sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTabTap sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFireEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fireAction sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTap sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doFire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callParent sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.dispatch sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.doPublish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
b.implement.callSuper sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.publish sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onRecognized sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.fire sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTouchEnd sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.invokeRecognizers sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onTouchEnd sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.define.onEvent sencha-touch-all.js:21
(anonymous function) sencha-touch-all.js:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been dumb,

For some reason my icon field of my TabPanel was set to true and not an URL.

That's why I had this error, obviously not the best debug trace.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having some problems during lazy loading. Whenever you use a class that you didn't include in `requires: []` array, Sencha (or ExtJs) would try to load a file for that class. And file name will be parsed from the class name. For example if you have a class 'MyApp.view.View1' Sencha would try to load a file /MyApp/view/View1.js.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The behavior is the same whether you require it or not.

Comment: Well to me everything is set in the requires: [] ? am I missing one ?

Comment: @rixo: not for the built application :)

Comment: @Fawar: I just tried to point you to the right direction. There is some issue with your application and you would still need to figure this out :)

Comment: @sha  To me everything is added and there is nothing else in the app, so im wondering how is it suppose to help me or what am I supposed to understand from that, which could help me out?

Comment: Then I'm afraid we need to see more code. Preferably in some kind of fiddle to help you further.

Comment: I don't think it's working. I'm getting error message 'Failed to save files' and nothing is displayed after that.

Comment: I haven't fiddled all the app has it in different files and its getting big thanks to architect. its the Tabbar file in which the error appear when switching tab.